# Set breaking point based on wrapper and not screen size

Tags: css, container-queries

I am building a website that have different pages which will have wrappers with different width. I would like to set breaking points for inner divs based on the wrappers and not the screen size. Is this possible to do?

I only used media queries before but that obviously won't base it on which wrapper I'm using.

Comment: it's possible to use media queries if the wrapper doesn't have a fixed width.

Comment: no it's not possible